# exc_bad_access while writing to output stream with cfnetwork

Tags: ios, objective-c, smtp, exc-bad-access

I am working on an iPhone application. I am trying to send message with one URL with smtp via the gmail server. I use the CFNetwork framework. Sometimes mail is sent without problem , but many times I get an exception exc_bad_access at the line exc_bad_access if

```
(CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(outputStream))
```

1 Class : HSK_CFUtilities

```
CFIndex CFWriteStreamWriteFully(CFWriteStreamRef outputStream, const uint8_t* buffer, CFIndex length)
{
    CFIndex bufferOffset = 0;
    CFIndex bytesWritten;

    while (bufferOffset < length)
    {
        if (CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(outputStream))
        {
            bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(outputStream, &(buffer[bufferOffset]), length - bufferOffset);
            if (bytesWritten < 0)
            {
                // Bail!                
                return bytesWritten;
            }
            bufferOffset += bytesWritten;
        }
        else if (CFWriteStreamGetStatus(outputStream) == kCFStreamStatusError)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Pump the runloop
            CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.0, true);
        }
    }

    return bufferOffset;
}
```

2 Class : SKPSMTPMessage in method `parseBuffer`

```
 case kSKPSMTPWaitingSendSuccess:
                {
                    if ([tmpLine hasPrefix:@"250 "])
                    {
                        sendState = kSKPSMTPWaitingQuitReply;

                        NSString *quitString = @"QUIT\r\n";
                        DEBUGLOG(@"C: %@", quitString);
                        if (CFWriteStreamWriteFully((CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, (const uint8_t *)[quitString UTF8String], [quitString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) < 0)
                        {
                            error =  [outputStream streamError];
                            encounteredError = YES;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            [self startShortWatchdog];
                        }
                    }
```

I was wondering if you could give me a hint with it? I would appreciate any help . Thank you in advance, Best regards.

Comment: you managed to resolve? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Kalaichelvan : Yes, I managed, Please check my answer for this problem, Hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it was `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error so

In my Case when I made `strong` `property` of `SKPSMTPMessage` in needed .h class & used

`SKPSMTPMessage` object as global for needed class, It worked.

[image]

Here's a great link on what causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS and how to track down the root problem:

[Lou Franco's Understanding EXC_BAD_ACCESS](http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access)